# how to save selected checkbox value in database instead of true false in Angular 4

Tags: angular, checkbox

Here I have some checkbox and I want to save their data value not ture  and false to server. If I click on checkbox then I am pushing group id in array and that group id I want to save in database.

This is the My Html Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="group._id" formControlName="group_id" formControlName="group_id"(change)="getCheckboxValues($event,group)" /><span innerHTML="{{group.group_name}}"></span>
```

This is my ts file code goes here :
here I am pushing only group id

```
getCheckboxValues(event,id){

    debugger;
    const checked = event.target.checked;
if (checked) {
    debugger
 this.selectedGroups.push(id._id ); // push the Id in array if checked
  } else {
      debugger
  const index = this.selectedGroups.findIndex(list => list.user_id == id);//Find the index of stored id
  this.selectedGroups.splice(index, 1); // Then remove
}
```

}

```
    // World View Question
worldViewQuestion = function (data) {
    debugger;
//  const videodisplaygroup =this.selectedGroups;

    if (this.worldViewForm.valid)

        data.group_id = $('input[name=group_id]:checked').val();



    $("#worldView").val("SAVING...").attr("disabled", true);
    this.authService.SaveWorldViewQuestion(data).subscribe(data => {
        debugger;
        if (data.success) {
            //console.log({...this.worldViewForm.value,videodisplaygroup})
            $.growl.notice({
                title: 'Success',
                message: data.message
            });
        } else {
            $.growl.error({
                title: 'Error',
                message: data.error
            });
        }
        $("#worldView").val("SAVE").attr("disabled", false);
    });
}
```

I want to save group id in videodisplaygroup
this is my data structure
[here is the videodisplaygroup parameter where I want to store value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etMxE.png)

Please your help would be great

Comment: can you please add your code in stackblitz so that i can help you out

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I have save it database but  how to make condition if id is available ind database then checkbox  should be checked, it is not update to view

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" [checked]="write your condition" value="group._id" formControlName="group_id" formControlName="group_id"(change)="getCheckboxValues($event,group)" /><span innerHTML="{{group.group_name}}"></span>`  write your condition in the checked and let me know if you face any problem

Comment: can you give any example of condition.

Comment: `[checked]="group_id"==group.id` ?

Comment: Do you have any ngFor for the checkboxes can you please add that even if you have so that i can write the condition

Comment: sure let me add

Comment: `<div *ngFor="let group of my_groupList" >
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="group._id"
                                     [name]="videodisplaygroup"
                                     formControlName="videodisplaygroup"
                                     (change)="getCheckboxValues($event,group)" />
                                    <span innerHTML="{{group.group_name}}"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>`

Comment: try this  `[checked]="group._id!=undefined"`

Comment: sorry but why undefined 
?

Comment: if the groupid is not present then it will not be checked.... Did this work??

Comment: I used  it but it is showing checked all

Comment: As every object in the group has some id it will be checked.... Do you have any object which doesn't have id..?? console your object and see whether it has id or not

Comment: `Array(4)0: cat: "My Groups"id: "5c9b52580737ae188c5be14b"itemName: "Waz 2"__proto__: Object1: {id: "5c8f6c2ea2c9eb1418f8fb1b", itemName: "WAZ admin", cat: "My Groups"}2: {id: "5c8f6769a2c9eb1418f8fb04", itemName: "WAZ Tech", cat: "My Groups"}3: {id: "5c1903dbe9eba101140025f1", itemName: "surgery", cat: "soceity Group"}length: 4__proto__: Array(0)
`

Comment: using ng for I am getting this value in view page then after checked  value is storing like below

Comment: `videodisplaygroup: Array(2)
0: "5c8f6c2ea2c9eb1418f8fb1b"
1: "5c9b52580737ae188c5be14b"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: Are you there ?